# How to get only json that match a particular value

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the input json

```
 set = {
  "pending": [
  {

    "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",

  }, {
     "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",
  }, {
     "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86l89u",
  }]}


 set = set.pending[0].filter(({ po_id }) => { 
    return po_id === 'm86lu';

 });
```

I need to get only json set that has po_id 'm86lu'.

The output needs to be like this

```
set = {
"pending": [
  {

    "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",

  }, {
     "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",
  }
  ]}
```

How do I get it? Looks like I am using the `filter` function incorrectly.

Comment: `Looks like I am using the filter function incorrectly.` -- would be nice if you showed us your attempt

Comment: `set = set.pending.filter(({ po_id }) => { 
    return po_id === 'm86lu';

 });`

Comment: create a loop, loop through each key of json and use comment's suggest, assign each new return to the key and add to a new set. Don't try to finish everything within one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pending key would be lost in that way

```
  set = {
       pending: set.pending.filter(({ po_id }) => { return po_id === 'm86lu'; })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through json, add to new set one by one based on the suggestion from comment.

```js
var input = {
  "pending": [
  {

    "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",

  }, {
     "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86lu",
  }, {
     "is_active": true,
    "order_updated": false,
    "po_id": "m86l89u",
  }]}

var output = {};

for (var key in input) {
    if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    let content = input[key].filter(({ po_id }) => { return po_id === 'm86lu'; });
    output[key] = content;
}

console.log(output);
```